# Simple C Error: “… undeclared (first use this function)”

Tags: c

I am working on my first C program for school. For some reason I am getting the following error when I try to compile it

```
#include <stdio.h>

int multiplication()
{
    int i, j, k;

    for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
             if (x[k] == 0)
              return 0;
             a[i] = a[i] + b[j] / x[k];
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: What is `a`, `b` and `x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to declare `a`, `b` and `x` or receive them as arguments to your function before you can use them